# Handling Assignment operators ambiguity in Android Studio(Kotlin)

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, ambiguity

I recently started developing android apps in kotlin and have across this issue.
I have var employees Arraylist declared and assigned null at the start of my activity, which I later add string values to in my OnCreate method.

[image]

```
var employees: ArrayList<String>?= null
```

Now,when I add values to it I get an Assignment  operators ambiguity error.

[image]

Upon doing some research on the internet I found that  += operation with a mutable list has two possible interpretations - either to append an item to the existing list or to create a new list by appending the new value to the old list and to store the reference to the new list in the variable.
[from here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/compiler-error-assignment-operators-ambiguity-all-these-functions-match/5069)

Now my question is how do I make the compiler choose from one of the interpretations to add to my mutable list.

Thank You.

Comment: Please always post your code as text instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just choose one by yourself, depending on your requirement.

If you just want to add an employee into the `employees`:

```
var employees: ArrayList<String>? = null
employees?.plusAssign("employee")
```

If you want the `employees` be assigned to a new `List` which contains the added employee:

```
var employees: List<String>? = null
employees = employees?.plus("employee")
```

Note the difference between the declarations. But I think it's better to add an employee just using the `add()` function of `ArrayList`:

```
var employees: ArrayList<String>? = null
employees?.add("employee")
```

I think there is no need to stick to the assignment operator after all, it's just a convenient way to the method calls :)

Comment: Thanks a lot,the plusAssign worked for me. But Strangely enough, while using add and plus,i get null value assigned to var employees

Comment: if you use add or plus, then no need to assign to employees, they just modified the employees. the add and plus method has no return value.

Comment: I am doing this,
`employees?.plus("hello")` then
`employees?.add("hello")`
`Log.i("employees",employees.toString())`   
which gives: 
 I/employees: null

Comment: you should init employees first, employees = ArrayList<String>()

Comment: For me, there is a reason to want to use `+=`. When designing a Kotlin Gradle plugin that should have minimal syntax change from Groovy to allow users to convert easily. https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl

Answer (score 5):

If you use `val` instead of `var`, the operator will work as desired:

`val myArrayList = arrayListOf<String>()`

`myArrayList += "firstElement"   // works fine`

Comment: Thats great... but why?

Comment: Found the "why" [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/compiler-error-assignment-operators-ambiguity-all-these-functions-match/5069)